# Perl style regular expression for C comments

Tags: c, regex, comments

At work, I have a requirement to create a perl-style regular expression for C comments (/*) for comments left in our code.  Our business analysts had new requirements, and these were all prefaced with "BA", and I'm supposed to somehow scan the comments to find these instances.  I am very unfamiliar with regular expressions and after reading more about them, I'm lost as to how to target comment blocks with only the BA string.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you are looking for comments containing BA? You mean like this?: `/* stuff BA stuff */`. Please give an example of exactly what you need to match. Did you try doing a search first? (Matching a C comment is a question that has been asked and answered.)

Comment: @user964210, be aware that there is no _single_ regex pattern that doesn't trip on stuff like this: `s = "foo /* bar";` (i.e. a `/*` inside a string literal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any weird escaping rules for C comments, so I think you just want something like this:

```
/\/\*.*?\/\*/s
```

The `s` flag means that the `.` will also match carriage returns, so the comments can cross multiple lines.

To match only comments starting with "BA", you'd want:

```
/\/\*BA.*?\/\*/s
```

Consider adding the `i` flag if the "BA" part can be lowercase.

Comment: Actually I think you want `/s` as your suffix. `/m` means that `^` and `$` will match the beginning or end of any line instead of the whole pattern, which doesn't do a lot of good here.

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I needed.  For cases like this, is there a simple way to negate the regular expression?  For example, if I wanted to match all comments that don't contain BA?

Comment: @user964210 - Try `/\/\*(?!BA).*?\/\*/s` or `/\/\*(?!\s*BA).*?\/\*/s`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -regex ".*\.[ch]" | xargs grep -regex "/\* *BA"
```

What that does:

- Find all your C source and header files.
- Search each of those files for "/*" followed by any amount of whitespace, followed by "BA".